# ExoPlayer - throws UnrecognizedInputFormatException on MergingMediaSource

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using ExoPlayer to play videos from external storage. In my use case some of the videos have separate audio file. So I need to merge them for playing. When I use *MergingMediaSource* , it throws *UnrecognizedInputFormatException* .

Here is my code

```
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
MediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(audioUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
MergingMediaSource mergingMediaSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, audioSource);
```

When I use this mediaSource it throws following exception

```
2019-05-24 18:36:41.084 4283-4441/me.entri.entrime E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor, AmrExtractor) could read the stream.
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:973)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:891)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

But when I try playing them separately, it works fine.

Comment: Hi, Did you find out the solution of merging audio with video?

Comment: I couldn't find the exact reason why it happened but when I updated ExoPlayer library to latest and used ProgressiveMediaSource, the problem got resolved @ShriyaPandya